# ListViewItemCollection in Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, listview, casting, ienumerable, parallel.foreach

I want to manipulate all entries in a ListView, preferably in parallel.

```
Parallel.Foreach<ListViewItem>(auftraegeView.Items, line => 
{
    line.Font = new Font(line.Font.FontFamily, someInt);
});
```

That refuses to work though, because

> cannot convert from ListViewItemCollection to IEnumerable

ListViewItemCollection doesn't offer methods like `ToList()` or such.
I a sort of for-the-laughs-and-giggles-attempt I made a cast

```
(IEnumerable<ListViewItem>)auftraegeView.Items
```

That didn't throw a Compiler-Error, but caused an InvalidCasTException at runtime.

Note:
The pointy brackets are inversered intentionally so they don't get eaten up as HTML here.

**Question:**
Is there a way to convert `ListView.Items` / `ListViewItemCollection` to something that implements the IEnumerable-Interface, hence works with `Parallel.ForEach`?

Comment: try this cast: `auftraegeView.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>()`

Comment: Yes, possible. but You should not deal UI with multiple threads. Reading is barely acceptable but writing is not. What is `line.Font`?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Well, yes. The cast does work and then I get an exception, saying more or less "thou shalt not manipulate UI multithreadingly". Thumbs up for your prediction and the reminder that this not only doesn't work but would also be horrible practice.

Comment: One suggestion: Font is "Immutable" so you can share the font objects when they are same. You can cache the fonts somewhere.. instead of creating `new Font(line.Font.FontFamily, someInt);` n number of times

Comment: @SriramSakthivel done that. Calling a new ctor for the same font for every Item, brilliant me :D. However the performance bottleneck is still the drawing itself so I guess I'll have to live with it.

Comment: Either you have have a small number of items in the `ListView`, which means you don't need parallelization. Or you have many items, which is not useful, because no user will go through many thousands of items. In that case, you should figure out some way to filter the items, or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Parallel.Foreach(auftraegeView.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>(), line => 
{
    line.Font = new Font(line.Font.FontFamily, someInt);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Works just as intended, but dies for other reasons(See the other comment on OP). The more you know.

Comment: And what does it "die" on? Show the errro

Comment: *System.AggregateException ---> System.InvalidOperationException Cross-thread operation not vaild. Control '' accessed from a thread other than it was created on.*  
Basically what Sriram Sakthivel predicted.

Comment: @Mark Yup, so the lesson is don't use worker thread with UI(Although I used it for reading very carefully ;))

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I just wanted my quadcore to not sit around semi-busy, while I can actaully watch my ListView getting redrawn. Turned out to be a bit like this: http://xkcd.com/292/

Comment: If you have to do it on the UI, make sure you use `Invoke()`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Your question was probably answered, but maybe you should consider another way how to set FontFamily of lines. It should be UI stuff. Try to declare it in styles or if you want do change font dynamically, use some kind of triggers.

Comment: I'm doing this dynamically. When I scoll the mousewheel while holding ctrl this occurs. More code here http://pastebin.com/nkrDy2zY

Comment: Yes I understand. I'm talking about decoupling UI from ViewModels. You shouldn't change UI from code directly but only through binding.